# UTF-8 Encoding issue in EntityManager data transfer to mySQL

Tags: java, jpa, jsf-2.2, glassfish-4

I have 2 projects that both use a same mySQL database. One is a Master/Detail desktop application, the other one is a JSF Crud using PrimeFaces-4.0.
- Although my JDBC Connection is UTF-8 as:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

- Database fields are also utf-8_general_ci
- And I defined Glassfish JDBC properties as:
  useUnicode , true
  characterSetResults , UTF-8
  characterEncoding , UTF-8

But I still get '?' characters into my DB when I input non-English Strings!

Comment: try this http://mathiasrichter.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/character-encoding-utf-8-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when we started to use Hibernate. Assing additional configuration to the connection URL didn't solve the problem, however we did add the following properties

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
```

and that what solve the problem. Try removing parameters from URL string and leave it be so it would be just like

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

EDIT:
I just noticed that you are not using Hibernate at all so this will not help you ;/

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I'm not using Hibernate! I use JPA!

Comment: `useUnicode=yes`, shouldnt it be `useUnicode=true` ?